# Makefile - get arguments from .ini/.yml file

Tags: python, makefile

Is it possible to have a Makefile grabing arguments from either config.ini or config.yml file?

Let's consider this example, we have a python main.py file which is written as a CLI. Not we do not want users to be filling arguments to a python CLI in terminal so we have an example config.ini file with the arguments:

PYTHON FILE:

```py
import typer

def say_name(name:str):
    print('runnig the code')
    print(f'Hello there {name}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(say_name)
```

```
config.ini FILE:

[argument]
name = person
```

```
Makefile FILE:

run_code:
    python main.py ${config.ini.argument.name}
```

Is it possible to have a project infrastructure like this?

I am aware that Spacy project does exactly this. However I would like to some something like those even outside NLP project without the need of using spacy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find, or write, a tool which will read in your `.ini` file and generate a set of makefile variables from it.  I don't know where you would find such a thing but it's probably not hard to write one using a python module that parses `.ini` files.

Suppose you have a script `ini2make` that will do this, so that if you run:

```
ini2make config.ini
```

it will write to stdout makefile variable assignment lines like this:

```
config.ini.argument.name = person
config.ini.argument.email = person@somewhere.org
```

etc.  Then you can integrate this into your makefile very easily (here I'm assuming you're using GNU make) through use of GNU make's automatic include file regeneration:

```
include config.ini.mk

config.ini.mk: config.ini
        ini2make $< > $@
```

Done.  Now whenever `config.ini.mk` doesn't exist or `config.ini` has been changed since `config.ini.mk` was last generated, make will run the `ini2make` script to update it then re-execute itself automatically to read the new values.

Then you can use variables that were generated, like `$(config.ini.argument.name)` etc.